# Can I filter charts in Qliksense without it affecting the filters of other charts in my sheet, without using alternate states?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to have 2 combo charts, one with a filter looking at one branch's sales and one looking at another branch's sales, so I can compare performance for the next few months since there's a big project being implemented. But the filters keep affecting both charts rather than one.
I'm unable to use 'Alternate states'. I'm on Qlikesense Enterprise accessing it through Chrome and at my company, we've been told to stop using the desktop app so I don't have access to any streams on desktop. Only on the cloud version so I can't create another states.

'=Sum({<Dimension1='BranchName'>}Sales)' Then another very similar one, but with a different 'BranchName'.

But I'm not getting the sales figures. Only the line of another measure. Then another very similar one, but with a different 'BranchName'.

Comment: It might just be a typo but the set analysis syntax should be =Sum({<Dimension1={'BranchName'}>}Sales)

Comment: Why you cant use alternate states? QSE is supporting them. is it because you cant duplicate the published app?

Answer (score 1):

One way I handle these situations is to utilize variables and the dropdown variable input object.

1. Create two new variables in the frontend, one called `vBranch1` and the other called `vBranch2`. The definition of either variable should be the branch names you want them to default to.

[image: Qlik Sense variables dialog box screenshot]

2. Add two variable input objects to your dashboard and set them to either variable, make them dropdowns, and then choose the **Dynamic** values option with the following expression:

`=Concat(all distinct [Branch Name], '|')`

That expression is concatenating all distinct Branch values in your branch field with the pipe `|` symbol, regardless of other selections (thanks to the `distinct` and `all` keywords).

[image: Qlik Sense variable input object screenshot]

3. In your combo charts, use set analysis in the measure(s) to filter to whatever branch you have selected in the variable dropdown:

`Sum({<[Branch Name]={'$(vBranch2)'}>} [Sales Amount])`

And now you have combo chart comparison that will react to non-branch selections, but will stick to whatever branches you've selected in the variable dropdowns:

[image: Qlik Sense combo chart comparisons with variables screen recording]